# ListView: How To Make Selected Items Stay 'lit'

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using a ListView to display a list of items.  I tap on one item to 'select' it, and that item briefly turns orange in the list, but then returns to the background color.

How can I cause the item to stay 'lit' until I unselect it (by tapping the item again)?

Also, can I call a method that will clear all selected items for that list?

Comment: clearChoices() does the job for clearing selected items.

Answer (score 0):

You need a state list

In res/drawable creates a list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/orange" />

</selector>
```

In your layout for the listview items add the code below to the main framelayout

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Make sure that `orange color` is defined in `res/values/colors`

Comment: How do I define orange color in res/value/colors?  NOTE: it doesn't have to be orange, I don't care, anything that highlights the selected item will work.

Comment: <color name="powder_blue">#b0e0e6</color>

Comment: You may also need to set your listview to setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

Comment: I tried the above, but it doesn't work.  I created file: res/values/colors.xml with this contents: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="orange">#b0e0e6</color>
</resources>

is that what you meant?

Comment: Also, this doesn't compile.  javac can't find the symbol: setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

Comment: do it in the listview xml android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selector and then in onListItemClick() use **setSelected(true)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/orange" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/list_default" />
</selector>
```

Also override my onListItemClick() method:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);
    view.setSelected(true);
}

EDIT:
public class YourClass extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
    view.setSelected(true);
}
```

}

Comment: I added the onListItemClick() code above (without the view.setSelected(true);) and received lots of compiler error messages.  The messages were 'illegal start of type' and lots of  ';' expected.

Comment: Make sure your class implements OnItemClickListener. See my edit and follow the class structure.

Comment: If I change my code to implement OnItemClickListener as in your example, then I get lots of javac error messages: LinearLayoutDemo.java:24: com.commonsware.android.linearpct.LinearLayoutDemo is not abstract and does not override abstract method onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?>,android.view.View,int,long) in android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
    [javac] public class LinearLayoutDemo extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    [javac] LinearLayoutDemo.java:90: setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener) in android.view.View cannot be applied ....

Comment: Also, what file does the selector go in?

Comment: res/drawable/list_selector.xml?

Comment: This isn't working.  Is it really that difficult to configure the ListView so that an item stays 'lit' once you select it?  That should be the default.  Surely there's an easier way.